# Velocity (VM) template: how to disable for a block of jquery

Tags: jquery, parsing, velocity

I have Apache Velocity.
I have some jQuery code.
I think VM doesn't like when I do things like `$img.css("float","left")`.
How can I completely disable VM parsing within a block of HTML/Javascript ?

Thanks

Comment: could you fix the "tenplate/template" typo in your question? It makes your question less visible.

Comment: indeed, I haven't noticed it. Fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For short examples, like the above, if it isn't a legitimate Velocity reference, just do $img and Velocity will ignore it.

It's tempting to escape the reference, but this is extremely quirky.  If $img is a real reference, then \$img will display $img.  But if $img is not a Velocity reference, then \$img will display \$img.

The best bet, especially if you have a long block of text you do not want parsed, is to put it in a separate file and use #include, which does not parse the include text.

#include("file.vm")

This will include "file.vm" directly into the output without parsing it.  (If you want to include text and parse that text, use #parse).

Answer (score 9):

Velocity [1.7-beta1 is now out](http://velocity.apache.org/news.html#engine17beta1), and it ships the `#[[don't parse me!]]#` directive, so you don't have to escape a bunch of code in your .vm files.

Works for me like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [the user guide](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#escapingvalidvtlreferences) it looks like as long as you don't have a variable named `$img` in velocity, you shouldn't have a problem with velocity parsing it.  Otherwise you can escape with `\$img`.

As far as actually having the parser skip over the the string as you would with a CDATA tag in XML, I'm not sure how you could do that.

Answer (score 1):

The \ escaping is unreliable.  Do:

context.put("D", "$");

and then

${D}img

In the upcoming 1.7, there is a new #[[ parser will ignore this completely ]]# syntax.  Hopefully a 1.7-beta1 will be out soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can [escape the dollar sign](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#escapingvalidvtlreferences) in Velocity by preceding each $ sign with a backslash...

```
\$img.css("float", "left");
```

Comment: And if that fails you (because of an "invalid reference")... you can create a Velocity variable to hold the dollar sign as a string value, the next section in the docs shows how and why...

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a variable to parse the dollar sign.
For example:

```
#set( $jQ = "$" )
```

Now you can use this variable to place a dollar sign where you need to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$jQ img.css();
</script>
```

Please ensure there's a space between the **$jQ** variable and the **img.css();** (so that velocity doesn't try to interpret the rest as a different variable).  You won't have to do this if a parenthesis follows directly after the $jQ var.

This would be fine:

```
$jQ('#smithySword');
```

Answer (score -1):

The `$` in jquery is a shorthand for `jQuery`, therefore you can substitute any `$` with `jQuery`